# My iPhone 6 screen is not showing all my apps, they are half way down the screen

Tags: ios, iphone

My apps on the screen are not showing all the way at the top. They are showing only on half the screen and I can't see all the apps.

Answer (score 1):

That’s Reachability. Double-tap the home button to move the screen down (on iPhone 6 and 6 Plus size displays) so you can reach the top of the display one-handed. You can tap the area above or double-tap the home button again to return to normal.

Answer (score -1):

@grgarside is right. You need to double-tap the home button (Notice it's not double-press, as that activates the app switcher).

For more information: Apple introduced this feature for larger-screened iPhonesThis is called Reachability. The feature makes it quicker and easier to reach to content at the top of the screen.This is currently available on the iPhone 6, iPhone 6 Plus, iPhone 6S, iPhone 6S Plus, iPhone 7 and iPhone 7 Plus.

A double-tap, or -touch, will move the top half of content on the screen down to the bottom half of the screen. You can then tap on a link or button, or scroll through a list or webpage. After tapping on the screen, the content will slide back to its normal position.

(reference: https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-use-reachability-on-iphone-6-6-plus/)